# how avoid undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm tring to write a js module for node js.The module is simply:

```
var sum=function(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

var product=function(a,b){
    return a*b;
}

exports.sum;
exports.product;
```

And I call the module in this way:

```
var op=require("./sumProduct");
console.log(op.sum(3,4));
```

And the error is throw. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(op)`? Do you see your `sum` function listed?

Comment: Try `exports.sum = sum; exports.product = product;`?

Comment: Just to be sure, there is no extension on your sumProduct file ?

Comment: Reading [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) may benefit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember this line: `module.exports = exports = {}`

What does it mean? That `module.exports` is simply an object.

To be sure it isn't empty *and* that it contains everything the programmer needs to export, avoid the common mistake of overwriting it, or in your case, not writing to it at all.

This is the problem in your code:

```
exports.sum;     // Nothing is actually happening
exports.product; // in either of these lines.
```

Both `exports.sum` and `exports.product` are undefined after exiting the sumProduct module. There is no assignment of values to the `module.exports` object.

Your code can be fixed succinctly as follows:

**Method 1**

```
exports.sum     = function (a, b) {
  return a+b;
}

exports.product = function (a, b) {
  return a*b;
}
```

Alternatively, you can construct your module in either of these ways:

**Method 2**

```
module.exports = {
  sum: function(a, b) {
      return a+b;
  },

  product: function(a, b) {
      return a*b;
  }
};
```

**Method 3**

```
var sum     = function (a, b) {
  return a+b;
}

var product = function (a, b) {
  return a*b;
}

exports.sum     = sum;
exports.product = product;
```

Answer (score 2):

You had it so close.  Instead of your exports lines, use this

```
module.exports = {
   sum:sum,
   product:product
};
```